# How to Copy Row to another Google Sheet based on Cell Value Including Formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to copy rows of data from one Google Sheet to another Google Sheet based on cell value and have got it down to the following code. How can I also include the formatting? E.g I have some highlighted colour cells from my source sheet that I would also like to have in my destination sheet done via the query.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("GoogleSheetWebsite", "A:AB"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28 where Col23 = 'Name' OR Col24 = 'Name' OR Col25 = 'Name' OR Col26 = 'Name' OR Col27 = 'Name' OR Col28 = 'Name'", 1)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is highlighted cells based on value, use conditional formatting in the second sheet.  When the source sheet data changes, the cell colors in the second sheet will change to reflect the changes in the source sheet.

There is no regular formula to change the color of the cells.

Here is a little example:
[image: Pending Screenshot]
[image: Completed Screenshot]
[image: Pending and Completed Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please explain? Basically in my source sheet i have names highlighted either orange (pending) or green (confirmed). I am copying the rows across using my above script, then would also like to update these orange or green highlighted cells in my destination sheet for each name once they are confirmed and when i update the source sheet highlight colour.

Comment: I added an example to the answer.  It does not matter how the information arrives at the spreadsheet.  The conditional formatting custom formula is just evaluating the cells in Column B to determine whether they contain the strings "Pending" in the first screenshot and "Completed" in the second screenshot.  The third screenshot shows both conditional formatting rules in effect at the same time.  You can also highlight the whole row as well.  Simply apply conditional formatting to the entire range and add $ before the column letter in the custom formula.  This will highlight the entire row.